# Non-pass/fail Jenkins result

Tags: performance, testing, jenkins

Is there a way to make Jenkins accept and graph test results that aren't binary passes/fails?

I'm writing a performance test for an Open Source project I contribute to. After each successful build, I would like Jenkins to run a bash script I've written, then report as the test result a value I compute during the test. The value would be on the order of 10k, if that matters. The idea is to allow devs to view the historical performance of the codebase, as well as how their commits changed it.

I'm new to Jenkins, but I've Googled pretty hard and found nothing relevant. Links are appreciated, even if you don't have a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) should be able to do what you need; you can store the test results in csv format and then graph them across all builds.